# How to handle dynamic sub domains for a single domain on the fly through htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

What i am trying to achieve is that i want a user to signup and create an account on

`www.my-domain.com` .

Then he can access his file from the address

`www.username.my-domain.com`

similarly for all the users.

Please suggest me the best way to manage this and an example on how to do this?

Also how will it distinguish between

`www.my-domain.com/news` and `www.username.my-domain.com/news` ? both these are separate files

I have set up a wildcard for the domain with just * entry in the A record type and copying all other addresses from those set for the ftp and www. but when i access my site with

`abc.my-domain.com` it throws a 404?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem in the redirections. Anyone want to set up a wild card DNS for his domain can add an A-record with the value * in the first column and then copy all others as above that record then you can have your Wildcard setup. you can check that by writing ANYTHING.yourdomain.com to verify that the wild card is working.